# How to return to activity with changed ImageView

Tags: android, android-activity, android-imageview

I am new to android development and I am currently doing an android app which has 2 activities say Activity A and Activity B. Activity A contains an ImageView which changes source image when clicked.The problem is that , when I clicks the ImageView it changes the source image and now when I go to Activity B and return back to Activity A I has the old image source in ImageView not the changed one. How can I overcome this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity
{
    private int imageId = R.drawable.image1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // TODO : Attach layout, retrieve layout elements, etc.
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        // Get bundle and set imageView
        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            imageId = savedInstanceState.getInt("imageId", R.drawable.image1);
            image.setImageResource(imageId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt("imageId", image);
    }
}
```

The above code will save some parameters and restore it once your class will resume.

Answer (score 1):

You should store your current image as a bitmap in the savedInstanceState, so you can store any image which is in the current ImageView. A better way to use the savedInstanceState is to use the onRestoreInstanceState method. This method will only be executed if there is a savedInstanceState available.

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {

    private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        // Read the bitmap from the savedInstanceState and set it to the ImageView
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) savedInstanceState.getParcelable("bitmap");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(img);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {        
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        // Save the image bitmap into outState
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        outState.putParcelable("bitmap", bitmap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you go to activity A from B，I think if you return A by the back button ,that will accord with your plan.But if you make intent to go to A,maybe you create another activity A. I'm not sure wether I'm right,I'm new to android too.

Comment: Thanks, I go to activity B from A by a button( using intent) and returns back by by back button.

Comment: I think that I use onBackPressed method with intent to start activity A .This might be the problem.